# How to create UIPageviewcontroller within container using iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have created UIPageviewcontroller Inside the container with two sub view controllers for page navigation. Now the problem Is I have set the constraints for container on mainviewcontroller like below

[image]

Issue : Need to control the container. its showing top side  and hiding top custombar and landscape also Its not sowing. I have create container on base view. the base view have good constraints.

Comment: explain your problem more clearly, how it is showing currently, add screenshot.

Comment: Please check now i have updated @Shubhank

Answer (score 0):

For above issue We need to set like below

```
// Add the page view controller to this root view controller.
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
[self.containerView addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```