# Dismiss PageViewController and load a new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

i have been working on an pageViewController in swift and xcode. I used the default template in xcode and made a pageViewController application. But now i want to place a button on the pageViewController that shows on all pageViewControllers and when tapped that button the pageViewController dismissed and the RootViewController screen is shown back.
I have written this line but this does nothing.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But this is of no help. Can you please tell me how can i achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [popToRootViewController()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller). You could have a nav bar with a button that calls this function so that whatever view you are currently on, it will pop to the rootviewcontroller.

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. See here for why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259

Comment: I don't have a navbar. I have view controller and there is a button at the bottom right.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can use container for your pageViewController. Should be something like this:
[image]

Comment: @Evgn i dont understand. Can you explain?

Comment: You should have simple UIViewController which will be contains ContainerView. This container will be presented PageViewController.
Main structure for this solutuion you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260515/how-to-create-uipageviewcontroller-within-container-using-ios-objective-c)